# general sql exception logging

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have a class where all things related to sql are handled which is called sql helper.
now what i want to achieve is , to catch all exceptions that occer from this particular class and log them.Since this class is called from several places and already has more than 25-30 methods in it. I find it tedious to go to each and every method to write exception handling.

This is windows application Is there any better way to handle this.
For eg the way we have in asp.net

```
Application_Error()
 {

 }
```

Comment: Why not simply have the methods rethrow the exception and let the caller catch it?

Comment: You could also look at handling the [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx), but I'd probably go with re-throwing the exception and let the caller catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyExceptionHandler);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Comment: A *potential* downside is that this will catch every unhandled exception, not just the SQL Helper ones.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.ThreadException` will allow you to catch unhandled exceptions without terminating the application.

`AppDomain.UnhandledException` will terminate the app when the method exits.